# Writing Video File with opencv

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am using opencv 3.1 with python3.Here   below is my code.I am unable to correctly save the video in mp4 format.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
w=int(cap.set(3,1920))
h=int(cap.set(4,1080))
fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Data/hasans.mp4',fourcc, 25, (w,h),True)
count = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
count = count + 1
print ("processing frame ", count)
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret == True:
    cv2.imshow('test',frame)
    out.write(frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you can try this code with VideoStream on  [imutils.video](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/video/videostream.py) it is an excellent package to deal with video files with opncv.

Answer (score 0):

There are some caveats for writing video with `fourcc` in OpenCv. In a practical way, try to use `.avi` as output format.

Im not sure if it is possible to directly export a video in `.mp4` as it is a compressed format. So, this would require extra steps.